# Python: Does Having Old Laptop Impact Runtime on Looping Programs?

Tags: python, runtime

I'm running a self implemented algorithm on my personal laptop using python 3.8.  It's taking over 5 minutes to run while other people seem to be able to run it in 2 min or under.

I have an old laptop.  Does this impact my runtime significantly?

Comment: If your laptop is half the speed, it will take twice as long to do the same thing.  For a small task that takes only milliseconds, that may not be significant; for something that takes on the order of a minute, it will be very noticeable.  If you shared your algorithm/code people might be able to make suggestions on how to speed it up, but given the same code and different hardware, the better hardware is going to win.  This is in no way unique to Python.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be told if it will impact **significantly** or not without seeing your algorithm and your hardware specs.

**But having old hardware will surely impact your program runtime.**
You can optimize your code for your hardware specifically to improve runtime.

> Although python is very flexible and can run well in older devices.